# permissions and rights on a shared drive

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, chmod

I don't understand exactly how things work and how to solve the following correctly.

I have a mounted HD to my server, to this I upload and download photos from domain X. This works perfectly. Domain x has these owner/group numbers: 2000/5000, I can upload and download the photos from folders with 755 permissions. Now I am working on a second website with domain Y, on the same server and it needs to access the same mounted HD. Domain Y has owner/group: 3000/5000.

How can I give both domains access at the same time? Should all folders be given permissions 777? Brief explanation or a link to a similar case would be very welcome.